# Python: Split based on condition but only split part of condition

Tags: python, regex

I have the following String

```
random_string = '12:58 PM word \n12:20PM person \n12:39PM'

I am doing the following:
re.split(r'[\n]+\d',random_string)

And I get:
['12:58 PM word ', '2:20PM person ', '2:39PM']

But I want:
['12:58 PM word ', '12:20PM person ', '12:39PM']
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From   https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html  :

> `(?=...)`
>   Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.

So, in your case:

```
>>> re.split(r'[\n]+(?=\d)', '12:58 PM word \n12:20PM person \n12:39PM')
['12:58 PM word ', '12:20PM person ', '12:39PM']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookahead in your regex to avoid matching digit after newline:

```
>>> random_string = '12:58 PM word \n12:20PM person \n12:39PM'
>>> re.split(r'\n+(?=\d)', random_string)
['12:58 PM word ', '12:20PM person ', '12:39PM']
```

- Regex `\n+(?=\d)` will split on newline when a digit is just after the newlines.
- There is no need to put `\n` in character class.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, and thanks for adding an explanation as well, and not just the answer